# How to unzip string data in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, soap, unzip

Can you help me please?
I have problem to unzip the string data.

I tried lots of code for unzip string data But I am unable to found solution.

I am trying to parse data from soap web service. and it will returns below data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><TestGetNearByDonorListResponse xmlns="tempuri.org">
<TestGetNearByDonorListResult>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   
</TestGetNearByDonorListResult>
</TestGetNearByDonorListResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to parse SOAP web service & get data in Array.
data string returns a zip format. so how I can unzip string data ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That string is base64 format of a zip file, you need to decode that base64 first than you will get zip file, then you can unzip that file

Comment: Like : 

NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:response options:0];
    NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    NSLog(@"response : %@", decodedString);